# Button onclick location.href is not working

Tags: php

I want to redirect to a page using a `<button>` tag.. however, it's not working

`<?php $url2 = "mission_schedule.php?id=" . urlencode($_GET['id']);?>`

```
    <!-- this is not working -->        
    <button onclick=location.href='<?php echo $url2; ?>'; >Next</button>

    <!-- this is working -->           
    <a href="<?php echo $url2;?>">Next</a>
```

clicking the button reloads the same page.. while clicking the link redirects me to the right page
In addition, this button works in other pages normally

Comment: Try quoting the `onclick` value. Attributes should have their values in quotes.

Comment: you miss ":
<button onclick="location.href='<?php echo $url2; ?>';" >Next</button>

Answer (score 0):

Missing double quotes:

```
<button onclick="location.href='<?php echo $url2; ?>';">Next</button>
```

Comment: Gotta be fast :)